# C# WPF не выводится один из элементов коллекции в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс продукта:

```
public class Product : Window
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Sum => Number* Price;

    public static Product[] GetProducts()
    {
        var result = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Name = "Photoshop", Number = 1, Price = 20 },
            new Product { Name = "Illustrator", Number = 1, Price = 10 },
            new Product { Name = "Dreamviewer", Number = 1, Price = 50 },
            new Product { Name = "Audition", Number = 1, Price = 15 },
            new Product { Name = "Bridge", Number = 1, Price = 15 },
            new Product { Name = "Flash", Number = 1, Price = 15 },
            new Product { Name = "Lightroom", Number = 1, Price = 15 }
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Есть листвью:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Product}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Name="ListV" Height="310" Width="360">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Наименование" Width="120" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="Цена" Width="50" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}" Header="Количество" Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Sum}" Header="Итого" Width="80" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <col:ArrayList x:Key="Product">
            </col:ArrayList>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

Есть запись продуктов в листвью:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListV.ItemsSource = Product.GetProducts();
    }
}
```

На выходе получаем отсутствие Name.

[image: Отсутствие Name]

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: О_о а почему ваш продукт наследуется от Window - уберите это, там же есть уже свойство Name

Comment: @Виктор как уже многие сказали - стоит убрать наследование от Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм :)

Судя по всему, вы наткнулись на небольшой баг WPF.

Давайте-ка его воспроизведём.

```
class BaseVM : DependencyObject
{
    public int X
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "X", typeof(int), typeof(BaseVM), new PropertyMetadata(13));
}

class DerivedVM : BaseVM
{
    public int X { get; } = 44;
}
```

Мы создали базовый класс, у которого есть dependency property. Потом создали производный класс, в котором мы наше dependency property экранируем обычным свойством. Привязываемся, выводим на экран:

```
<Grid TextBlock.FontSize="24">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

и получаем

[image: тупо баг, коллеги]

---

Что нужно сделать? Всё просто. Как совершенно верно замечает @Андрей, ваш VM-объект не должен наследоваться от окна. Просто замените `public class Product : Window` на `public class Product`. Эта ошибка должна уйти.

Comment: Это не баг, думаю. WPF сначала ищет `DependencyProperty` и если находит - дальше не ищет. Ведь `XProperty` у нас никак не перекрыто. Такой класс тоже выведет 13: https://pastebin.com/TEzsz7tv "Обвеска" из обычного свойства над депенденси всего лишь для удобства человеков, WPF она не требуется, WPF будет нормально работать и без нее. В общем надо курить документацию...

Comment: @Андрей: Но ведь по идее WPF должна работать со свойствами из most derived-класса?

Comment: Должна ли? WPF просто вызывает `GetValue`/`SetValue` если они есть, а они в данном случае есть

Comment: @Андрей: Я думал, что алгоритм должен быть таким: (1) найти most derived-свойство (2) выяснить, что это за свойство (DP, INPC, обыкновенное), (3) использовать в соответствии с этим

Comment: А как выяснить, что это DP? Проверить наличие `static {Name}Property`? Так оно есть - значит у нас DP? :)

Comment: @Андрей: Ага, именно так. В любом случае, они делают по-другому, сначала ищут XProperty, судя по всему.

Comment: Такова реализация, и в текущей реализации, думаю, это не баг - по другому и быть не может. Хотя как изначально задумывалось - неизвестно и рассматривался ли такой кейс вообще...

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, можно сначала рефлексией поискать тот (родительский) класс, в котором определено свойство. И в нём уже искать всё остальное. В любом случае, XProperty они ищут наверняка через рефлексию. Хотяаааа, DependencyProperty.Register наверняка складывает информацию в `Dictionary<Type, ??>`, так что для DP рефлексия минимальна (только пройтись по цепочке типов).

Comment: Исходники, кстати, открыты, хранится всё в `HashTable`, в качестве ключа выступает пара `name, ownerType`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш класс `Product` наследуется от `Window` - вам это скорее всего не нужно, подумайте об этом еще раз.

---

По сути вопроса.

Дело в том, что [класс `Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) наследуется от `FrameworkElement`, который уже имеет [свойство `Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx), которое, в свою очередь, на самом деле всего лишь оболочка над [свойством зависимости `NameProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.nameproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). Таким образом, ваш класс также имеет свойство зависимости `NameProperty`.

А WPF работает со свойствами зависимости в разметке по особому - он вызывает напрямую методы [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms597473(v=vs.110).aspx), а вся "обвеска" из обычных свойств просто игнорируется.

Это документированная особенность поведения WPF: [Implications for Custom Dependency Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties#implications)

[<sub>Связанный вопрос на en.SO</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071187/6766879)

---

Если всё же вам требуется наследовать этот класс от `Window` (в чем я еще раз усомнюсь), вам придется переименовать свойство `Name`, оно уже занято, это цена наследования.
Ну или просто переиспользовать - это тоже будет работать (просто удалите строчку `public string Name { get; set; }` из своего класса).

---

И еще: всегда обращайте внимание на рекомендации студии даже если ваш код компилируется и запускается:

[image: скрин]

Такие сообщения следует игнорировать только если вы на 146% уверены что всё нормально, но даже в этом случае код можно переписать так, чтобы этого предупреждения не было.